# Get an error of Unknown provider $routeProvider when upgrade angular form 1.1 to 1.3

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I try to upgrade angular 1.1.X to 1.3 and I got the error below:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
>   Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeProvider
>       at http://localhost/web/js/third-party/angular1.3.20.js:63:12
>       at http://localhost/web/js/third-party/angular1.3.20.js:4031:19
>       at getService (http://localhost/web/js/third-party/angular1.3.20.js:4178:39)
>       at Object.invoke (http://localhost/web/js/third-party/angular1.3.20.js:4210:13)
>       at runInvokeQueue (http://localhost/web/js/third-party/angular1.3.20.js:4125:35)
>       at http://localhost/web/js/third-party/angular1.3.20.js:4134:11
>       at forEach (http://localhost/web/js/third-party/angular1.3.20.js:326:20)
>       at loadModules (http://localhost/web/js/third-party/angular1.3.20.js:4115:5)
>       at createInjector (http://localhost/web/js/third-party/angular1.3.20.js:4041:11)
>       at doBootstrap (http://localhost/web/js/third-party/angular1.3.20.js:1455:20)
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20…%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fweb%2Fjs%2Fthird-party%2Fangular1.3.20.js%3A1455%3A20)

MainMenusCtrl.js

```
angular.module('app.MainMenusCtrl', [])
.controller('MainMenusCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, SearchService, $location, $timeout, FormService, PropertyService){...}
```

app.js

```
    angular.module('app.controllers',['app.MainMenusCtrl',...]);
    angular.module('app.validators',[...]);
    angular.module('app.services',[...]);
    angular.module('app',         ['app.controllers','app.validators','app.services',..])
   .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

        $routeProvider.when(':formName',{
            template: '<div ng-include src="templateUrl"></div>',
            controller: 'RouteCtrl'
        });
        $routeProvider.when(':headName/:formName', {
            template: '<div ng-include src="templateUrl"></div>',
            controller: 'RouteCtrl'
        });
    }
]);
```

html:

```
    <script src="js/third-party/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/third-party/angular1.3.20.js"></script>
    <script src="js/third-party/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/third-party/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.scrollTo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/third-party/keypress.js"></script>
    <script src="js/third-party/ng-upload.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/third-party/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/third-party/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/third-party/ui-calendar.js"></script>
    <script src="js/third-party/date.js"></script>
    <script src="js/third-party/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>              
    <script src="js/third-party/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/third-party/bootbox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/third-party/sortable.js"></script>
    <script src="js/third-party/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/third-party/jquery.simplecolorpicker.js"></script>
```

I am not sure what's wrong, if someone could give me some hits would be good.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if it will solve that problem but you have missing `,` on the third row in app.js

Comment: Try using the un-minified version of `angular.js` while developing; the error messages are more verbose. Also, can you show the `<script>` tags from your HTML file?

Comment: @Dvir  No,that is not the problem..

Comment: What does the error message look like now that your using `angular1.3.20.js` instead of `angular.min.js`?

Comment: @Phil I update the error message now

Comment: I wonder what was causing the previous error message about `$controllerProvider` seeing as it is now about `$routeProvider`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you add ngRoute to the list of dependencies of the module that uses it.

```
   angular.module('app.controllers',['app.MainMenusCtrl',...]);
   angular.module('app.validators',[...]);
   angular.module('app.services',[...]);
   angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'app.controllers','app.validators','app.services',..])
   .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

        $routeProvider.when(':formName',{
            template: '<div ng-include src="templateUrl"></div>',
            controller: 'RouteCtrl'
        });
        $routeProvider.when(':headName/:formName', {
            template: '<div ng-include src="templateUrl"></div>',
            controller: 'RouteCtrl'
        });
    }
]);
```